# Check for Correct Implementation of CWAC-RichEdit Library by Commonsware

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I am developing a module in my first application on a note-taking functionality for users. The CWAC library was a valuable resource and tool provided for overcoming my challenges in understanding how to format the text along.

I have managed to import it as a project in Android Studio and followed along the lines of instructions on how to implement this library in the ReadMe section posted: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit

Here is the layout of my Notetaking activity class:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.example.hotel.moeccefamilytime.ReflectionNotes">

    <com.commonsware.cwac.richedit.RichEditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editor"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"/>
    <requestFocus/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Following that, here is the activity source class:

```
public class ReflectionNotes extends Activity{

    RichEditText rEdit;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reflection_notes);

        rEdit= (RichEditText)findViewById(R.id.editor);
        rEdit= new RichEditText(getApplicationContext());
        checkText(rEdit.getText().toString());

       // rEdit.setOnSelectionChangedListener(this);
    }

   /* public void onSelectionChanged(int start,int end,List <Effect<?>> list){

    }*/

    public void checkText(String m){
        if(m.length()>0){
            rEdit.enableActionModes(true);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.reflection_notes, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I have tried utilising the setOnItemSelectedListener as well, but however when any text entered is highlighted, there is no formatting options shown (only the default copy, paste, tick icon are displayed as usual).

*My inexperience with programming makes this question sound trivial, however I would appreciate help from expert programmers and developers to advice me on this. Thanks again.*

Answer (score 0):

Delete:

```
rEdit= new RichEditText(getApplicationContext());
```

And, since you do not appear to be calling `checkText()`, move `rEdit.enableActionModes(true)` to `onCreate()`, after you have retrieved `rEdit` via `findViewById()`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. However, I have been trying different methods but it still throws the following Class Not Defined exception upon execution after correcting the codes:

E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.commonsware.cwac.richedit.R$menu
            at com.commonsware.cwac.richedit.RichEditText.enableActionModes(RichEditText.java:333)

Comment: @Learn-veloper: Sorry, but I do not know what you might have done that would explain that specific symptom.